# How to design the blocking queue with move-only objects?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, queue

I want to implement the class `Queue`, that will handle only movable objects:

```
class Object {
  public:
    Object(Object&& other);
    Object(const Object&) = delete;

  private:
    Object() = default;
};
```

And I have a problem designing the `Pop` method in an atomic way. It must atomically (1) pop the object from the queue and (2) somehow indicate the result of operation. The result is required in case the queue is closed and empty - to prevent hanging. If the queue is empty, but not closed - the invocation of `Pop` should block.

**My approaches.**

If the method accepts the reference: `bool Pop(Object& obj);` - then someone should already have an unused instance of `Object`, and it's not possible all the time.

If the method returns the temporary: `Object Pop(bool& result);` - then I don't know what to return in case of "closed and empty".

**Note:** it's not allowed to make friends `Object` with `Queue`.

How can I properly design the pop operation?

Comment: Why isn't `Object Pop(bool& result);` sufficient? What's `result` here?

Comment: @avakar If the pop was successful, then `result=true`. If the queue was closed and is empty, then `result=false`. If queue is empty I can't return anything except `Object()`.

Comment: Is this queue to work a multiple thread environment? I ask because it doesn't make much sense for queue to be considered empty if another thread can just push elements into it concurrently. A "closed" queue is another matter. So maybe you need something like a publisher-subscriber, where the publisher notifies subscribers that an element is ready to be popped from the queue.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, as mentioned by tags. You have an interesting suggestion - I'll rethink if the publisher-subscriber is a good replacement. But the first puzzle that comes to mind is spurious wake-ups - they will possibly lead to the popping from an empty queue as well.

Comment: You can also return a `std::optional<Object>` (AFAIK, this is part of C++14, but implementations exist as part of Boost and elsewhere.) You might also consider doing this in a method called e.g. `try_pop`, and let `pop` be blocking (if writing multithreaded code) or throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, you have several options when someone calls `pop` and the queue is empty.

One is actually blocking. This of course only works when you have the hope that someone else will put something in the queue while you are blocked and waiting (i.e. multithreaded code.) As you have mentioned, there are also problems when the queue is shutting down.

Another is throwing an exception when there is nothing to pop. However, some people have legitimate (and sometimes ill-founded) apprehensions about using exceptions in C++.

Another method I like and recommend (if you don't want to throw) is returning an `optional<T>` object, i.e. a wrapper for `T` that *can* be empty.

It was supposed to be part of C++14, but it seems that it has been pushed into its own technical specification, which means that I don't know when it will be standardized. Let's forget this fact however, and see how one can use it:

```
#include <optional>

// I've omitted proper "queue" class stuff for brevity,
// and assumed the underlying queue has an STL-like interface
std::optional<Object> pop ()
{
    std::optional<Object> ret;
    if (!internal_queue.empty())
    {
        ret.emplace (std::move(internal_queue.front()));
        internal_queue.pop_front();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

There are of course locking and other details that are omitted. You would use the above like this:

```
auto x = q.pop ();
if (!x)
    LOG ("Failed to pop an item.");
else
    USE (*x); // *x is an Object
```

Since your objects do support moving, this will be quite an efficient implementation. Also, I'd suggest naming the above method `try_pop` or something similar, in order to better indicate what it actually does.

Since `optional` is not part of the C++ language yet, you can see whether your compiler happens to implement it already (it's not a complicated piece of code!) Or you can use **Boost.Optional**. Or you can implement it yourself, or use other implementations that ought to be available around the web somewhere.

All in all, if it was my code, I'd write a `pop` method that blocks if necessary and returns an `Object`, and throws only when the queue is being shutdown (i.e. there won't be any more objects coming.) And I would also implement a `try_pop` that returns an `optional<Object>` for when you don't want your code to block or to deal with exceptions.

Comment: Very nice solution with `std::optional`. But at least the libc++ implementation requires the default constructor.

Comment: @abyss.7, Hmmm, weird. Are you sure about that? I have implemented `Optional` myself, and using a `union` (or an array of chars) along with a forwarding `emplace` method, you do not need default constructors. I can't find the exact proposal, but this page ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional ) explicitly states that default-initializing an `optional` object shall mean that it is *disengaged* (i.e. *empty*.)

Comment: @abyss.7: If you look at this reference implementation ( https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/blob/master/optional.hpp , look for `storage_t`) from the proposal paper (N3793,) you'll see that it stores the optional T inside a union with a dummy char, so it can avoid constructing the object when the `optional` object is empty.

Answer (score 4):

Just return an `Object` in the normal case and throw an exception if the queue is stopped and empty when `pop()` is called (or a `pop()` is active when the queue is being stopped).

Comment: I really think returning an `optional<Object>` is the better choice here. It doesn't really seems necessary to take away the choice from the upper-layer programmer and force an exception on them. Specially since all the `optional<T>` implementations I've seen would indeed throw an exception if used while they are empty. So, the user has a choice: just use the return value and deal (or not) with the possibility of an exception, or check the return value explicitly and be assured that no exceptions will be thrown. Am I missing something?

Comment: @yzt: I really think imposing a extra branch (either the user has to inspect whether the optional is set or the optional has to do so; the latter being the _far_ worse choice) on the user to find out known information again is bad choice of interface design. Throwing an exception in the exceptional case is the cheaper approach for the normal case (sure, if you create a queue for processing at most one object it will be worse but I think that would be an abnormal use). So _I_ really think throwing an exception is better choice (likewise, I'd rather avoid a virtual dispatch).

Comment: Well, that of course makes sense, but there are contexts that the possibility of an exception being thrown is much more expensive than one simple branch. That's why I think having both a throwing `pop` method and a `try_pop` method that returns an `optional` is best. And the interface will be quite clean, with well-understood names and conventions. Anyway, you make good points and I'm not trying to convince you, of course. :)

Comment: I don't understand the bit about virtual dispatch. Are you suggesting that implementing an `optional` requires virtual methods/destructors?

Comment: @yzt: Another answer suggests the use of `std::function<...>` which internally uses some form of virtual dispatch: that is also adding a non-zero cost (which can be avoided by using a deduced function object). I just also looked at the other responses. I'm not suggesting that an `optional<T>` uses a virtual function.

Answer (score 1):

Dietmar Kühl's answer (`Object pop()` which throws an exception) seems like a good choice to me, but another approach that, depending on how you intend to use it, may be useful is to have `pop()` call some other function if anything is popped. As yzt mentions, this isn't just popping, so perhaps shouldn't be named `pop`.

```
void pop_apply(std::function<void(Object)>);
```

Call it as

```
queue.pop_apply([](Object obj)
{
  // do something with obj here
});
```

It could potentially be improved by making it return `bool` for the benefit of the caller, to know if anything was popped, or by making `pop_apply` a templated function that allows anything callable to be passed in without wrapping in a `std::function<>`.

Comment: Why not at least have the `pop` method be templated on the type of the callable object it will receive, so you don't pay for the overhead of a `std::function` when you pass in a nice lambda? Also, IMHO, a more suitable name for this method would be something like `pop_apply`.

Comment: @yzt To keep my answer simply, mainly. You do raise a good point, which does deserve at least a mention, and I do like your name better. Will edit.